RPI-Python-Sockets: socket still see packets after network stream ends. Do they get buffered?
my application requires me to detect multicast streams and react to them.  Defining the sockets and igmp is fine but once the stream(s) ends , the select seems to stay active for 60 seconds.
   readable, _, _ = select.select(sockets, [], [], 0)  

I've tried to zero out the timeouts I know about but to no affect.
===============================
import socket
import struct
import time
import select

multicast_addresses = {'224.0.1.10': [50002, 50003,50010,50024]}

sockets = []
active_ports=[]

active_MC ={
            "50002":[False],"50003":[False],
            "50010":[False],"50024":[False]
            }

for multicast_address, ports in multicast_addresses.items():
    for port in ports:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.bind((multicast_address, port))
        group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_address)
        mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
        #sock.setblocking(False)
        sockets.append(sock)
        
#print (sockets)

while True:
    # List of sockets to monitor for read events
    readable, _, _ = select.select(sockets, [], [], 0)  # Timeout set to 1 second
    print("just after readable", readable)
    
    # If any of the multicast sockets are in the readable list, it means there's incoming data
    #print(f'the lenght of readable : {len(readable)} {readable}')

    #print(readable,end='/r')
    #print (f"streams dected = {len(readable)}")
    #print(active_MC)
    port_check = '50003'
    length = len(readable)
    pass

    for sock in readable: # Create List of active ports
        port = sock.getsockname()[1] # get the name of one of the ports
        active_ports.append(port)
        print(f"active_ports array = {active_ports} type={type(active_ports)} {type(active_ports[0])}")        

        #note active_ports get stored as integers
        
    #print("After For loop acive Ports:",active_ports)

    #for port_check in active_MC.keys(): # loop through all ports defined
        #print ("Ports For loop read ",port_check,type(port_check)) 
        #print(f"Array Port_check = {port_check} ")

        # port_check is a str
    if int(port_check) in active_ports : # stream is active if true
        #print(f"Vars in first test port_check= {port_check} active_MC = {active_MC[str(port_check)][0]}")

        if active_MC[port_check][0] == False :# First time detected
            print(f"stream started on port: {port_check}\n\n")
            active_MC[port_check][0] = True
            print("MAIN: ",active_MC)
        else:
            # True Events may be ignored or Not
            # thinking I may need to time duration of stream
            #print("Failed First Test")
            pass

    else:
        print("main if statement was false\n",port_check,active_MC[port_check][0])
        # here Port is NOT an active stream so set to false and log
        if active_MC[port_check][0] == True :# Stream was live but no longer
            print(f"stream STOPPED on port: {port_check}")
            active_MC[port_check][0] = False
            print("POST: ",active_MC)
        else:
            print("POST if statement was false\n")
            # True Events may be ignored or Not
            # thinking I may need to time duration of stream
            pass
        
    active_ports.clear() # clear the array for the next text
    time.sleep(1)
        

    
    
            

In a previous generation of this code I setup 10 different threads each listening to one unique socket and using the recvfrom to determine if I have traffic or not.  I'm pretty sure that caused a memory leak because I had crashes every 38 days from a reboot (almost exactly) once that was implemented.  I figured a more efficient way is required.

You are using a reserved multicast address. See IANA IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry].
